# Origin of the expression "Gone for a toss" in Indian English

Tags: idioms, subcontinental-english

I recently heard the expression "gone for a toss", which in Indian English means afaik "broken beyond repair" or "completely out of order".

What is the origin of this expression? Is it borrowed from Cricket?

Comment: I assume it's origin is something like *needs to be tossed out*.

Comment: It appears in a script of Steptoe and Son (TV Series 1962–1974) as [*I had intended breaking in here, pinching some grub, robbing you of all your money, taking your car and off. That's all **gone for a toss,** ain't it?*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1fkLAQAAMAAJ&q=%22gone+for+a+toss+ain%27t+it%22&dq=%22gone+for+a+toss+ain%27t+it%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y). I suspect it's Cockney (it reminds me of *Gone for a Burton*, used with exactly the same sense).

Comment: Whatever its origin, I'd be careful how I used it in Britain!

Comment: There is *to take a toss* also, meaning "to suffer a fall from a horse".

Answer (score 4):

The expression "*gone for a toss*" appears to be a typical Indian one, and its derivation from cricket might be a  reasonable assumption:

From ***[The Hindu](http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-features/tp-bookreview/know-your-english/article996161.ece):***

> - (M. Sajith, Malappuram) Very often we hear someone saying, ‘My new cell phone has gone for a toss' or ‘My plans went for a toss.' What do they mean by this? Well, when a teenager says that his cell phone has gone for a toss, he means that it has stopped working or that it is not working properly. Similarly, when someone's plans go for a toss, things don't go the way he/she had anticipated or planned.
> - This frequently heard expression is used only in India; native speakers of English do not say ‘gone for a toss'. They would probably use the word ‘haywire' in some of the contexts. They would say, ‘My cell phone has gone haywire' and ‘My plans went haywire'.

The *toss* in cricket is actually  used  to refer to an element of unpredictability, the idea of somethning out of your control:

> - The [toss](http://www.thehindu.com/sport/cricket/the-importance-of-a-toss-in-cricket/article7449047.ece) is a tribute to the element of luck that is at the base of cricket. Even those who are in control of their destiny — the great batsman, the successful bowler —know the role of chance in their performance. The toss merely acknowledges this.

Comment: What would be native translation of:
We book the meeting room in advance but at the last moment , CEO would show up and hijacked the room and everything else would go for a toss.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much more obvious cricket derivation.  A "full toss" is a delivery that reaches the batsman without bouncing, and they are rarely done on purpose because they are so easy to hit.  They are worse than a wasted delivery.  So "to go for a toss" means to waste something horribly.